# connection to Oracle database in 64 bytes

Tags: php, oracle11g

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database (11g XE) on my x64 machine. I have XAMPP with PHP 7.2 x86, but when running my script it shows me this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function oci_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebaCustom\index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pruebaCustom\index.php on line 19
```

In a 32-byte machine it works correctly but not in the 64-bit machine, so understanding the problem. Can someone tell me if I should do a different process?

Comment: if you run `phpinfo()` do you see "--with-oci8" ?

Comment: @Dale I do not see the OCI extension in the phpinfo